# Is it possible to manipulate equations in R in order to find the expression for a specific subject of the equation?

Tags: r

as a beginner R programmer I am wondering if R can help to re-arrange an equation to make other variable as subject?

For example, if I have the equation x=2+y and when I want to make y as the subject of the equation, R would help me to re-arrange the equation into y=x-2 and display it as exactly that.

Is that possible in R? assuming the equation are a simple linear equation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Ryacas` (version 1.0.0, the latest one) you can do:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> yac_str("Solve(x == 2+y, y)")
[1] "{y==x-2}"
> yac_str(y_rmvars("Solve(x == 2+y, y)")) 
[1] "{x-2}"
> yac_expr(y_rmvars("Solve(x == 2+y, y)")) 
expression(c(x - 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed.